# Substitution or comparison?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

For the question,

$X^4 + \frac{9}{X^4} = (X^2 - \frac{a}{X^2})^2 + b$ I have to find the values of $a$ and $b$. I tried two solutions both included the expansion of brackets.

By comparing terms I obtained $3$ for $a$ and $6$ for $b$.

However when I tried to substitute using $b$, I obtained a value of $0$ for $b$.

Why is it not possible to solve by substituting and on a more general tone when is it possible to solve by substituting?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE ! Nice first post !  For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](/help/notation),
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773).  Nice observation that $a = 3$.  What did you substitute for $x$?  I would try $x = \sqrt[4]{3}$ so that $$6 = 3 + \frac93 = (x^2 - \frac{3}{x^2})^2 + b = 0 + b = b.$$  *To respond to your question, it **is** possible to solve this question by substitution.*

Comment: What do you mean by comparing and what do you mean by substituting and what how did you go about comparing and substituting to get those answers?

Comment: How I tried to use substitution was by stating b= and shifting the rest of the equation on the left side adequately correcting signs leaving solely b on the right side. Then using this expression for b I substituted it back to the original equation. I cannot specifically identify why this does not work. Thank you!

Comment: Did you trying substituting x = 0?  That will give you no answer at all as that will result in numbers divided by zero.

Comment: If "substituting" which is something I was never taught is what GNU Supporter then you can always solve by substitution except when i) you choose a value where the expression is not defined (e.g. x = 0 in this case) ii) choose values that yield dependent equations (e.g. x = 1 and x=-1 will give two equations exactly the same) or iii) the equation actually doesn't have any solutions (e.g.  $(x + a)^2 + b = (x+a)^2 + b + 7$)

Comment: "How I tried to use substitution was by stating b= and shifting the rest of the equation"  what equation?  "Then using this expression for b I substituted it back to the original equation" What was that "not original" equation?  If you have $(x + a)^2 + b = 9$ and do $b=9-(x+a)^2$ and then sub back you get $(x+a)^2 + 9 - (x+a)^2 = 9$ which will *never* work.  It will always get us $0=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X^4 + \frac{9}{X^4} = (X^2 - \frac{a}{X^2})^2 + b$

$x^4 + \frac {9}{x^4} = x^4 + \frac {a^2}{x^4} + b - 2a$

So by comparing $a^2 = 9$ and $b-2a = 0$.

So $a = 3$ or $a = -3$ and $b = 6$ or $b = -6$.

I'm not sure what you mean by substituting?  Do you mean picking an arbitrary  value for $x$ and getting two equations for $a$ and $b$.

Let $x = 1$.  then $10 = (1-a)^2 + b = 1 -2a + a^2 +b$ or $b= 9 + 2a -a^2$

if $x = \sqrt{2}$ then $4 +\frac 94 = (2- \frac a2)^2 +b = 4-2a + \frac{a^2}4 +b$ or $b=\frac 94 + 2a -\frac {a^2}4$

So $9-a^2 = \frac 94 - \frac {a^2}4 = \frac 14( 9 - a^2)$ so $9-a^2 = 0$ so $a = 3$ or $-3$.... and $b = 6$ or $-6$.

So how did you get $b= 0$?  Perhaps if we knew how you got that we can figure out what went wrong.  Did you divide by zero?  Did you get an redundant equation $0 = 0$ and mistake that for $b = 0$?

If $x = 0$ you get $0 + \frac 90 = (0 + \frac a0)^2 +b$ but this doesn't help us as dividing by zero is an absolute forbidden no-no that makes no sense.  If you make the error and assume $\frac 90 = 0$ (It does !!!!!!!!***NOT***!!!!!!!) then you get $0 = 0 + b$ (which is !!!!!!!!***WRONG***!!!!!!)

Of if you did $x = k$ and $x = -k$ you will end up with the redundant two equations: $k^4 + \frac 9{k^4} = (k^2 - \frac a{k^2})^2 + b$  repeated twice which gets us no where.

=====

from the comments it sounds like what you did was

$X^4 + \frac{9}{X^4} = (X^2 - \frac{a}{X^2})^2 + b$

$b = X^4 + \frac{9}{X^4}-(X^2 - \frac{a}{X^2})^2$ and then plug that back into the original

$X^4 + \frac{9}{X^4} = (X^2 - \frac{a}{X^2})^2+ X^4 + \frac{9}{X^4}-(X^2 - \frac{a}{X^2})^2$

$X^4 + \frac{9}{X^4}=X^4 + \frac{9}{X^4}$

$0 = 0$

Which is true.  Zero *does* equal 0.  But that doesn't help us in the least as it says nothing about $a$ or $ b$ or $x$.

If this is what you mean by "substitution" it will *NEVER* work.  You are simply defining something in terms of an expression and trying to solve the same expression with no new information and you simply eliminate everything in circular reasoning.

It's a bit like trying to do "Snoopy = Charlie Brown's dog.  Solve for Charlie Brown"

Charlie Brown = Snoopy's owner

Snoopy = Snoopy's owner's dog

Snoopy = Snoopy

Snoopy - Snoopy = Snoopy - Snoopy

0 = 0

Therefore Charlie Brown is nobody!

Hopefully you can see why that is wrong and how it will never work.

Comment: X^4 + 9/X^4 = (X^2 - a/X^2)^2 + b,

Comment: b = X^4 + 9/X^4 - (X^2 - a/X^2 )^2

Comment: This is what I meant by substitution.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that.  $b= x^4 + 9/x^4 - (x^2 - a/x^2)^2 = x^4 + 9/x^4 - (x^4 - 2a/x^2 + a^2/x^4 ) = 9/x^4 + 2a/x^2 + a^2/x^4$.  So what did you do then?  That's pretty messy.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot mate really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

you have $$x^4+\frac{9}{x^4}=x^4+\frac{a^2}{x^4}+b-2a$$ comparing the left and the right hand side we get $$a^2=9$$ and $$b-2a=0$$
can you finish this?

Comment: OP claims that it's *not* solvable by substitution, and asks for the **reason** for this.  Please see my comment to see that OP's claim is *false*.  IMHO, it's acceptable to skip OP's last question about the solvability by substitution "in a general tone".  However, I can't find the *reasons* in your answer.